# Query wildcard with IN

Tags: php, mysqli

I have this query:

```
select * from orders where week_of_year = '40' and user_id = '8631' and charge_date like in ('2017%','2018%') order by id desc limit 1
```

I have a syntax error near charge_date, I know the error I'm guessing I can't use like with 'in', is there anyway I can do the same logic that would actually work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, you need only year from the date and you want to search for multiple possible years.

Then your solution should look like below:

```
select * from orders where week_of_year = '40' and user_id = '8631' and YEAR(charge_date) REGEXP '2017|2018' order by id desc limit 1
```

**Update:**
Alternative Solution with `IN`

```
select * from orders where week_of_year = '40' and user_id = '8631' and YEAR(charge_date) IN (2017, 2018) order by id desc limit 1
```

Comment: Is `YEAR(...) IN (2017, 2018)` an option? No need to fire up the regex engine when you just compare integer values.

Comment: @Progman, Sure it is an option. Added as an alternative solution.